# Will uglify include a file twice if a wildcard selector is used

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs

Given my grunt uglify settings below; will the file `manager.js` be included twice in the resulting file `foo.js`? Or is uglify smart enough to figure out to not to include `manager.js` twice?

```
...
uglify: {  
    options: {  
        compress: true,
    },
    build: {
        files: {
            'dist/foo.js': [
                'js/manager.js',  // Other files depend on this - must be included first
                'js/*.js',  // Does this mean manager.js will be included twice?
            ],
        }
    }
},
```

Folder structure:

> ./js/manager.js
>   ./js/bar.js
>   ./js/baz.js

If uglify grabs the file twice, any recomendations how I can avoid this without having to manually add each javascript file?

Comment: it should be twice ,however i'm not sure about this pattern `js/!(manager)*.js`? anyway, you can use [filter](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#custom-filter-function) option

Comment: Why make it hard when you can move dependencies (*.js in this case) into subfolder..

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answer

> Given my grunt uglify settings below; will the file `manager.js` be included twice in the resulting file `foo.js`?

No, the content of `js/manager.js` will be first in the resultant file, (i.e. `dist/foo.js`), and will *NOT* be included twice using your current `uglify` Task configuration.

> Or is `uglify` smart enough to figure out to not to include `manager.js` twice?

Yes sort of, however it's actually `grunt` that works this out before passing an `Array` of unique file paths to `uglify`.

---

#### Long Answer

Excerpts from the grunt documentation for [Globbing patterns](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) read:

1. > Also, in order to simplify otherwise complicated globbing patterns, Grunt allows arrays of file paths or globbing patterns to be specified. Patterns are processed in-order, with `!`-prefixed matches excluding matched files from the result set. **The result set is uniqued**.

   The pertinent part here being: **The result set is uniqued**
2. The following code example is also given in the documentation:

   ```js
   // Here, bar.js is first, followed by the remaining files, in alpha order:
   {src: ['foo/bar.js', 'foo/*.js'], dest: ...}
   ```

To prove the points mentioned in the documentation, let's assume we have the following five source `.js` files stored in the `js/` directory. The pseudo content for each file is provided below the filename:

- **`manager.js`**

  ```js
  console.log('manager.js')
  ```
- **`a.js`**

  ```js
  console.log('a.js')
  ```
- **`bar.js`**

  ```js
  console.log('bar.js')
  ```
- **`baz.js`**

  ```js
  console.log('baz.js')
  ```
- **`quux.js`**

  ```js
  console.log('quux.js')
  ```

If we run `grunt` using the files listed above and your current `uglify` Task configuration the resultant output is:

**foo.js**

```js
console.log("manager.js"),console.log("a.js"),console.log("bar.js"),console.log("baz.js"),console.log("quux.js");
```

As you can see:

1. `console.log("manager.js")` appears first and only once (i.e. the result set has been uniqued).
2. The remaining files (i.e. those found via the glob pattern `'js/*.js'`) have been added in alpha order.